# Redirect after form validation fails

Tags: python, django

I have a template `question.html` that allows a user to answer the question through comments. If successful, it redirects to the original question page (`/question/10` or something similar).

Based on the form found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/), the view processing the comment looks like this:

```
def comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = CommentForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            # save, process, etc..
            # ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER']) 
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'question.html', {'form': form})
```

Question is: How do I ensure that this last render shows me the same `question/10`, without losing the information in the form? Should I handle the form validation in the `question` view instead?

Edit: Okay, based on answers given, I think I haven't specified the question enough:
The scenario is that there is a `DetailView` of an object `Question`, and I want to allow people to comment on that particular object using a comment form rendered on this same view. What I'm trying to find out is where to handle the post from the form, given that the page is rendered by a DetailView and not a formview.

- There are multiple DetailViews
- Each view uses a commentform
- If form validates, redirect to original page (url in hidden field, as ThiefMaster suggested?)
- Else, render original page with form in context.

Comment: Using the referer to redirect back is a bad idea. You should send the return URL via a hidden field instead (if it's not always the same one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you get from the comment form must already include question's id (because otherwise you wouldn't be able to associate the comment with a correct question). So if you know question's id you can get its URL using [reverse()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse).

Let's say the form field keeping question's id is called `question` and there is an URL pattern in `urls.py` file that handles the question page URL (`/question/10` or something similar) that is also called `question`. You would then do this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = CommentForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            # save, process, etc..
            # ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect(
                reverse('question', args=[form.cleaned_data.question])
            ) 
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'question.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks, I did not know reverse could be used this way. How would you then go about rendering the correct question page if the form is invalid? Simply by using the forms properties in the question template?

Comment: That's a separate question, but I think I would change the question view, so it can optionally take a comment form as an arguments (defaulting to a regular unbound form) and then do this for an invalid form:
`return question(request, form.cleaned_data.question, comment_form=form)`

Answer (score 0):

As you do not use ajax and render question form on every submit, be it successful or not, view processing a comment should know which question it answers and redirect to appropriate question view in both cases. The difference is in only that if comment is successful, it is saved to db and if not, you can choose to preserve entered values for better usability. But I don't see any place where you save a successful comment.

Comment: Ah, true. I've edited the question. Question remains; if a comment is unsuccessful (validation fails), how can I make sure that that final `render` shows me the correct question? Or in your words: How do I tell the view processing the comment to redirect to the question it answers without losing context?